# REGEXMATCH doesn't read or write the letter X

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match

I'm using the below nested formula for REGEXMATCH, most of it works fine. However, it appears REGEXMATCH does not read and give an output of the letter "X" any solutions?

=IF(RegExMatch(A2,"S"),"S", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"M"),"M", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"L"),"L", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"XL"),"XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"XXL"),"2XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"XXXL"),"3XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"lVXL"),"4XL",IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"VXL"),"5XL",))))))))

Believing the X is the issued I changed all my X's to E's and still no results
=IF(RegExMatch(A2,"S"),"S", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"M"),"M", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"L"),"L", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"EL"),"XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"EEL"),"2XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"EEEL"),"3XL", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"lVEL"),"4XL",IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"VEL"),"5XL",))))))))

**NOTE:** *I have nill Programming skills ( I learnt what I know through trial or error), I'm not an IT professional.*

Many Thanks

Ram

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXMATCH` isn't really needed. I would use [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) then check if A2 equals relevant strings (`A2="XL"`)

```
=IFS(A2="S","S", A2="M","M", A2="L","L", A2="XL","XL", A2="XXL","2XL", A2="XXXL","3XL", A2="lVXL","4XL",A2="VXL","5XL", true, "Invalid Size")
```